# How can I pass the source IP in a UDP server using Boost ASIO

Tags: boost-asio

I need to get the source IP for a datagram in a UDP server I'm writing using boost ASIO.
In the example udp datagram server the line:

Note: my current code is identical to the existing udp async server example in the boost asio documentation.

```
 socket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
        boost::bind(&server::handle_receive_from, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Is passing error and bytes_transferred.  I also need the address of the message.

Now I know I can use sender_endpoint_.address().to_string() directly, but I 
I would like to pass this in as a parameter.

So I tried placing sender_endpoint_.address() in as a parameter.
i.e.

```
socket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(data_, MAX_LENGTH), sender_endpoint_,
        boost::bind(&server::handle_receive_from, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                    sender_endpoint_.address()));
```

But the result is 0.0.0.0 when read from handle_receive_from.
However, if I simply access the sender_endpoint_.address() inside handle_receive_from
I get 127.0.0.1 which is correct.

How do pass this correctly? I need this because there are going to be multiple threads calling io_service.run() so a packet from another source may overwrite sender_endpoint and I need to be able to reply to that source packet.

Comment: can you post the code for your `server` class?

Comment: Currently it's identical to the async udp server example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that if you access sender_endpoint_.address() in your handler before you set up another async handler, it will be fine and not overridden.  You do call async_receive_from again in your handler, right, to be ready to receive another packet?

In your second code block, where you try sender_endpoint_.address() as a parameter, sender_endpoint_.address() is getting called when you set up the handler, not being executed by the handler when a packet is received.  That's why it'll always be 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Thanks, I did actually figure this out but haven't added anything in here.

Comment: UDP has a pseudo header where this encapsulated IP address. I don't know how to access it via Boost.Asio. However, the *port* is what you need to know about the sender.